# How to properly release UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uipopovercontroller

In the following code I alloc a UIPopoverController. Obviously I am not releasing it here because I am not sure where I should properly release it without a crash.

Where should I release it?

```
- (IBAction)photoLibraryiPad {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        popoverController.delegate = self;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:myButton.frame inView:self.view
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [imagePicker release];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a reference to it in your view controller and release it when you're done.

But in that case, you're both setting the property and creating a already-retained object.

Here, `[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];` creates a retained object that you *must* release.

But you're setting the property `popoverController` to that value, and the setter of that property probably retain that value.

You're retaining the popover twice and never releasing it.

You should :

```
UIPopover* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
self.popoverController = popover;
[popover release];
```

And when you're done with the popover :

```
self.popoverController = nil;
```

You should probably review your [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) to make that clear or use `ARC`.

Comment: Well I do, it is self.popoverController

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing the app with "Automatic Reference Counting" you don't actually need to worry about the release.

If you're not, or just curious anyway, you would release it in the delegate method that is called upon the dismissing of the popover.  Which would be:

– popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:

and/or

– popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:

depending on your implementation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I do that now but it says there is a leak in this method even though I do that

Answer (score 0):

(Without using ARC)

I personally decided to implement UIPopoverControllerDelegate and release it there:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [popoverController release];
}
```

Comment: It's very bad practice to send memory management messages to objects passed as parameters, they are considered to be autoreleased. Use properties or ivars.